# Set css class to list options dynamically AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

Well there are two list options in my code - Monthly and quarterly
I have one class "active" which generally highlights the element.

I need class "active" should be applied to one of the options when they are clicked or selected. Here class=active is applied to only Monthly manually. 
Looking for Angular solution for this.

```
  <div class="list">
           <p class="subheader secondary">Select Preferred View</p>
           <ul class="tabs">
           <li><a href="#monthly" ng-click="type='month'" data-ajax="false" **class=active**>Monthly</a></li>
           <li><a href="#quarterly" ng-click="type='quarter'" data-ajax="false">Quarterly</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-class directive like in a code below.

```
<div class="list">
           <p class="subheader secondary">Select Preferred View</p>
           <ul class="tabs">
           <li><a href="#monthly" ng-click="type='month'" ng-class="{'active' : type=='month'}" data-ajax="false" **class=active**>Monthly</a></li>
           <li><a href="#quarterly" ng-click="type='quarter'" ng-class="{'active' : type=='quarter'}" data-ajax="false">Quarterly</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

It adds specified class when expression given after classname evaluates to true and removes it when it evaluates to false.

```
ng-class="{'classname' : expression}"
```

You can set a default value in a controller:

```
$scope.type = 'month';
```

or via ng-init directive on div:

```
<div class="list" ng-init="type='month'">
```

[jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/o9wamydL/)

[jsfiddle with setting default in ng-init](http://jsfiddle.net/o9wamydL/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Here active class highlights Monthly by default and when I click on Quarterly now it highlights Quarterly but doesn't remove from Monthly. I want to toggle selection and keep active to monthly by default

Comment: Have you looked into jsfiddle? There active class is removed from Monthly. Setting default you can handle in a controller by setting $scope.type = 'month'; or by adding ng-init="type='month'" to the parent div